# Recommended settings for a small table with high update rate

Tags: oracle, update, oracle-12c, database-tuning

I have a small table which can be explained as follows:

```
create table mytab (
    primary_key_column number, 
    a number, 
    b number, 
    c number, 
    d number, 
    e number, 
    f number
);
```

It will have very few rows (not more than 256 records) but they will be updated at a high rate (for example one row could have up to 1000 updates per second).

What recommended settings should I use for the table to be able to handle this load and avoid update contention? Or other suggestions for doing this?

I will be using Oracle 12c or newer.

## **Edit**

Concerning the high nnumber of updates, as was asked in the comments.
With pctfree and initrans I can perhaps get each row in a separate block, but there will still be a lot of updates for a given key. So any suggestions on how to handle that?
I see only three ways forward on this.

1) don't update but write the increments to a separate table and then have a job summing them and do the update regularly. This will get me out of the update contention, but I will be doing a lot of inserts instead

2) change the primary key in some way, like

```
create table mytab(
  primary_key_column number,
  sub_key number,
  a number,
  ...
```

and then let updates choose a random "sub_key" for the given primary_key. Sub_keys could be like the numbers 0-99 to give each row only 1% of the updates.

Given that all values a-f are zero at start, the total values can then be gotten by summing over the primary key.
It's ugly, but it could work.

3. Might the In-memory feature solve the problem?

Any comments on this?

Comment: check PCTFREE and INITRANS(on table an PK index) parameters you want each line to reside in different block.

Comment: You said "one row could have 1000 updates per second".  Something tells me you aren't going to be able sustain calling `commit` "1000 times in 1 second" for very long.  It is a `speed of light` thing.  I'd love to see a system that proves me wrong.

Comment: @ibre5041, I would set PCTFREE to 99 and INITRANS to 255 I guess then.

Comment: Your small table will all be in memory anyway, so an in-memory feature won't help; it would address an I/O bottleneck if there were one, but yours is in concurrent access. Consider decoupling clients from the database by letting them queue updates (in AQ or application) and having a single thread perform DML and commit as (in)frequently as feasible.

Comment: @FORTRAN - it's impossible to say what a better design _might_ be, because we don't know the _business logic_.  All we know is some abstractly named elements and your assertion that there will be a lot of updates.  All I can say at this point is that it is _suggestive_ of a flawed design.

Comment: @mustaccio - a related topic to this queuing idea would be `Stream Processing` and `Stream Analytics`.  The `queuing system` is something like Apache Kafka.  As a reminder to everyone, the key to this type of performance is to do batch/bulk processing. ( SQL*Loader can insert 1 M rows in < 6 seconds )

Comment: @MichaelKutz there's no _processing_ in the picture painted by the OP, just storing data, streams might be somewhere upstream, if you pardon the pun.

Comment: Will the `1000 updates per second` be from 1000 separate sessions?  Or from one or two sessions?  If just one session, and that session just commits after every 100 or 500 updates, no problem.  If more than one session may be updating the same row, then you are going to have to commit after each update, and things will be slow, but you will just have to try and see.  I don't think it will be over one second to update and commit 1,000 times in a second, but I'll be curious to see.  And will other processes be reading the table during this?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 12c: Simple test case: one session inserting 256 rows:

```
MARK.STEWART@dev01> create table mytab (
    primary_key_column number,
    a number,
    b number,
    c number,
    d number,
    e number,
    f number
);

Table created.

MARK.STEWART@dev01>   insert into mytab (select rownum, OBJECT_ID, DATA_OBJECT_ID, NAMESPACE, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 256), DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 256),  DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 256) from dba_objects  where rownum < 257);

256 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.77
```

Updated a row 1,000 times and committed after each update, took only 0.29 of a seconds:

```
MARK.STEWART@dev01> begin
   2      for loop_var in 1 .. 1000 loop
   3              execute immediate 'update  mytab set a= 1 where PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN = 6';
   4              execute immediate 'commit';
   5      end loop;
   6  end;
   7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.29
MARK.STEWART@dev01>
```

With  `pctfree 99 initrans 20` it took almost twice as long (probably due to having high value for initrans): `00:00:00.65`

Comment: this is a test with single session. maybe the results were different if you had 1000 connections and 2 node RAC cluster.